# Exit Google Chrome’s full screen with applescript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I want to make an applescript to "Exit Full Screen" on a Chrome window, but nothing is working. I have no problem with the solution involving applescript clicking the correct menu item (hasn’t worked the ways I tried), the only requisite is that it does not use a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Do you mean *Javascript*?

Comment: Nope. [Applescript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applescript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking menu items doesn't work on full screen desktops, but the `exit presentation mode` command exits full screen.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1 to exit presentation mode
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        try
            tell w to exit presentation mode
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
```